# Clearance between moving parts

Tags: print-quality, prusa-i3, linear-motion

I am using a Prusa printer to print parts for prototyping. The project I am currently working on needs parts to be able to slide against each other and they need to be printed together. A bit like these [gears](https://www.prusa3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/gear.jpg), where the whole construction needs to be printed in one go and the gears need to be free to move afterwards. What clearance should one use between such moving/sliding parts to make it snug but not unmovable?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6570/) answers your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each printer will have different "print in place" tolerances, but you can find such a model with which to determine the numbers you seek.

One such item is on [Thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2375342):

[image: tolerance test model]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try one print to see what clearance I need.