# Why do straight lines on the top appear to be curved?

Tags: abs, tronxy-x5

I'm having a problem with my prints. Recently when I print rectangular pieces, the piece has an strange curve in one edge, it also has an strange patter in the surface. I have calibrated the bed but it doesn't change anything. What can I do to fix this?

I have a Tronxy cube X5 which I use together with Cura. I print in ABS at 230 °C.The print bed is set to 80 °C. I use a print cooling fan at 20 %. The layer height I set to 0.2 mm, the line width from the 0.4 mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to 20 mm/s for walls and 50 mm/s for infill. My retraction is 5 mm/off at 70 mm/s

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When measuring you need to make sure the caliper is parallel to the object you measure. From your images, the only valid measurement is the 2nd photo. This is a coreXY machine, are you sure it is printing square? Please print something like [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2280529) and measure the square and report back. Else it could be an extrusion problem or something. The top layer also appears to suffer greatly from under extrusion hence the curved lines.

Comment: Printing ABS slowly, at low temperature, without an enclosure sounds like a formula for warping.

Comment: @0scar Thanks for answer. I have just printed the test and this is the result:
https://imgur.com/a/Shc9LgH .
Under extrusion could be the reason of the problem?

Comment: Look at [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7002/corexy-calibration-issue), it might be helpful. There is an other test print to test for the diagonals, in case of a 200 x 200 mm the diagonals should measure 282.84 mm. There might be a problem with your frame or binding?

Answer (score 1):

> Why straight lines on the top are curve?

Apart from the dimensions, it appears that the top layer is suffering from extreme under extrusion, like there is hardly any filament being deposited.

Your last layer started printing at the lower right where it did print okay, but, when progressing to the left you see the starvation of filament flow resulting in sparsely filled in regions that look like curved lines on top of the print.

This could be heat creep, entanglement of the filament spool or an extruder problem.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate as a comment as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE This answers the question if you you look at the last image and the title of the question, so definitely not a comment imho. The curved lines are basically under extrusion results. I did made a comment on the caliper images, these appear irrelevant to the question title.