# What is wrong with my first layers?

Tags: print-quality, prusa-i3, calibration

I just assembled a Prusa i3 MK3 and went through the calibration process, but when I print the first layer doesn't look good and my prints come unstuck from the bed. I think it might be Z height but this was as high as I could put the probe without the paper moving on the calibration test. The layers after the first few look good but then the print either warps or comes unstuck and moves.

[image: Bottom view of a hexagon print]
[image: Detail of the bottom of another print]

Comment: Use a little more temperature.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the images you posted in your question, the first layer distance is too far away from the bed for the current filament flow.

This could either be related to:

- having an offset on the first layer like a height correction in the slicer,
- an incorrectly levelled (read height adjusted) bed, (you did the paper test correctly, so this is probably not your problem, it is mentioned for completeness)
- under-extrusion

  - slicer setting not correct, e.g. filament diameter or flow modifier not 100 %
  - incorrectly calibrated extruder

Your most likely problem is under-extrusion. It would be advised to calibrate the extruder: [How do I calibrate the extruder of my printer?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/how-do-i-calibrate-the-extruder-of-my-printer) and check the slicer settings.

Comment: plus one edge is extra far

Comment: Is 'live-Z' adjustment relevant here? Isn't there also a built-in calibration gcode?

Answer (score 1):

I used the live-z adjustment feature and set it to +0.150 and now my prints look much better.

Comment: You are running +0.150?  I am running more like -0.500.  It all depends on the position of the probe.  That live Z adjustment is important for good printing.  From the pictures, I would be inclined to make it smaller (toward zero or negative).