# Loss of resolution, burning, accretion of polymer at edges

Tags: resolution

I am printing 5-152 mm(L)x35 mm(W)x3 mm(T) samples using a commercial PLA filament with 0.1 mm layer height (30 total layers). The raster width is 0.4 mm while the raster angle in all layers is 0/0°. The bed temperature was 0 °C, while the printing temperature was 220 °C. The printing speed was 60 mm/s. The Z-axis compensation value is 0. I am seeing a loss of resolution, accretion, and burning of the polymer at the edges. What can be possibly causing this?

[image: Printed samples with burned edges]

Comment: Burnt filament usually comes from filament that has been cooked on the outside of the nozzle (e.g. in case of consistent over-extrusion). Please add by [edit] if you are having over-extrusion and if you have calibrated the extruder.

Comment: I have not calibrated the extruder. Can you please describe the method for calibrating the extruder? Another thing is that prints found in Creality Ender 6 SD card print perfectly without any over extrusion. If the extruder was not calibrated and over extruding, then those prints should also show signs of overextrusion.

Comment: Extruder calibration is found in [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/how-do-i-calibrate-the-extruder-of-my-printer). You could also lower the temperature 200 °C should work well with PLA at 60 mm/s.