# During a print, why must I continually adjust the Z offset to a more neagative number to keep the nozzle from air printing?

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis, nozzle, print-axis-offset, mriscoc

The nozzle is not clogged.  After an adjustment, I get two to three good printed layers then the nozzle begins to lift away from the print.  If I do not adjust the Z offset more negatively, then the print begins to go airborne in very small increments while extruding filament. I must babysit the print to get it finished.

A 20 mm cube (XYZ calibration cube) turns out with Z measuring 4.3 mm and X and Y both measuring 20 mm.  I have tried printing a model which I have printed many times without problems in the past but now it fails to print.  I have downloaded the XYZ calibration stl from Thingiverse and it fails to print without going airborne.

I have an Ender3 V2 Neo w/ BLTouch.  The default Z steps is 400 mm.  For calibration, I set it to 403 mm.  No improvement.  Then I set the Z steps to 380, 420, and 1200 mm without any change in the failed print results.  The V2 Neo is only 4 months old.  It has the most recent firmware but I re-flashed it anyway.  No change.  Then I downloaded from GitHub the mriscoc/Ender3V2S1 firmware. This firmware is awesome but it did not solve my problem.  I have replaced the Z stepper motor, no change.  My next step is to upgrade the motherboard from v 4.2.2 to v 4.2.7.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand that you print a cube of 20 mm in height, you adjust negatively to keep the layers being printed and end up with a 4.3 mm height object? This implies you should not adjust, you may have an extrusion problem; as in too less flow. You should first figure out it the Z-axis works correctly, create a G-code to home, level, move the nozzle to a Z height of 100 mm and measure the distance. This must be 100 mm; but if your story is correct you get a larger height. Because of baby-stepping the Z height your product becomes too short. Could you add some images?

Comment: I did a Z axis calibration, not by G Code.  I moved the gantry up 150 mm via the Move Z axis control.  The movement was 148.7 mm.  (150/148.7) X400 = 403, this is what I first set the Z steps to.  I have traditionally had to set the extrusion ratio to 90 to 93%.  I did set the ratio to 100% with no improvement.  The final 4.3 mm Z height is mostly likely the result of my over compensation of the Z offset.

Comment: So, your problem is extrusion!?

Comment: Thank you, I will try extrusion at 110% and see what happens.

Comment: You should check if extruding 100 mm of filament is indeed 100 mm, not randomly extrude more. You need to rule out possible causes.

Comment: Have you calibrated the extruder? See [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/how-do-i-calibrate-the-extruder-of-my-printer) for tips, I'll put the outcome of that in an answer to answer your question. We can then tidy up the comments.

Comment: What filament are you using? PLA?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your Z-axis calibration is off. First, ensure your Z-axis steps/mm are set correctly in the firmware.

Second, ensure your BLTouch is functioning correctly. Incorrect bed leveling information might be the cause.

Third, inspect your 3D printer's mechanical parts. Loose screws or belts might cause the Z-axis to drift.

Lastly, it's possible you're experiencing an extrusion issue. Make sure your extruder is pushing out the correct amount of filament.

And if all else fails, if you ask me, I would say upgrading your controller board could be a potential solution.